# Parent Container Values not Updating as Expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Project Background (Feel free to skip):
I am trying to make an idle game that uses SetIntervals to perform processes every so often and essentially pass an object down the line from one process to another, and so on. I am planning on having 3 levels (Purgatory, Heaven, and Hell which are all sibling components under a parent container), the objects starts and is generated in purgatory, and based on a soul's characteristics (good or bad) you get sent from purgatory to Heaven / Hell.

I am currently stuck appending the object sent from child to parent to an array in a state object. When I am appending the object to the end of the array, I have an output in my return that displays `array.length` for both state queues. It seems like the component may not be fully rendering as sometimes the values update, and sometimes they dont, and I am not sure why.

I am newer to react, so there maybe an interaction that I am missing here, so any help / advice / criticisms are welcome

Component structure:

- Content

  - Heaven
  - Purgatory (Child Sending to Parent)
  - Hell

Purgatory Callback:

```
    
export default function Purgatory(params) {
    const { handleAscension, handleDescension } = params;

    ...
    ...

    const handleDecision = (id, decision, soul) => {
        // Here we need to do the same as above. empty the one from the queue, and move to next step. probably return an object containing both the soul and the boolean "decision"

        if (decision) {
            console.log("Final: Ascended");
            handleAscension(soul);
        } else {
            console.log("Final: Descended");
            handleDescension(soul);
        }
    };
}
```

Content State objects:

```
    const [soulsAscending, setSoulsAscending] = useState({
        maxQueueLength: 10,
        queue: [],
    });
    const [soulsDescending, setSoulsDescending] = useState({
        maxQueueLength: 10,
        queue: [],
    });
```

Content handler methods:

```
    const handleDescension = (soul) => {
        let descensionData = soulsDescending;

        if (descensionData.queue.length >= descensionData.maxQueueLength) {
            console.log(
                "No room in the Ascension queue. This soul is left to roam in purgatory"
            );
            return;
        }

        descensionData.queue = [...descensionData.queue, soul];
        setSoulsDescending(descensionData);
    };

    const handleAscension = (soul) => {
        let ascensionData = soulsAscending;

        if (ascensionData.queue.length >= ascensionData.maxQueueLength) {
            console.log(
                "No room in the Ascension queue. This soul is left to roam in purgatory"
            );
            return;
        }

        ascensionData.queue = [...ascensionData.queue, soul];
        setSoulsAscending(ascensionData);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Shop />
            <Heaven soulsAscending={soulsAscending.queue} />
            <p>Heaven Queue: {soulsAscending.queue.length}</p>

            <Purgatory
                handleAscension={handleAscension}
                handleDescension={handleDescension}
            />

            <p>Hell Queue: {soulsDescending.queue.length}</p>
            <Hell soulsDescending={soulsDescending.queue} />
        </>
    );
```

EDIT: Added State variables

Answer (score 0):

I think that your descensionData, ascensionData is not updated.

Comment: Do you have any more information on this? What would need to be changed / why it’s not updating

Comment: React re-render when the state is updated. But, in your code it seems like descensionData and ascensionData is not a state. So, you might change descensionData & ascensionData to be state

Comment: The simple way to fix this problem is make setAscensionData & setDecensionData to update both. ( use it like setAscensionData(ascensionData.queue) ). Also, recommend you to read about state immutable in react(any of blog post)

Comment: Apologies, I see the confusion. I added the state variables in their own code block. These state variables are the ones being set.

Comment: @JakeRoberts How about to do let descensionData = structuredClone(soulsDescending);

Comment: so it seems to work for the first iteration of each array, which is farther than I was before. but after that it does not seem to want to update.

Comment: @JakeRoberts Use this > setSoulsAscending((prev) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        queue : [...prev.queue, soul]
      }
    });

Comment: I JUST Came across an article that did this and this was the resolution:

https://blog.logrocket.com/guide-usestate-react/#multiple-variables-one-state. Can you please provide this as an answer? and I will mark as answer

Comment: @JakeRoberts I think it might be the reason why your code not re-render that `const ascensionData = soulsAscending;` Object & Array is reference value. by assign soulsAscending to ascensionData, both has same reference address. So, React couldnt re-render which is related to state immutable.